# what's the most efficient way to solve this in python? testing Legendre's conjucture

Tags: python

Legendre's conjecture (proposed by Adrien-Marie Legendre in 1912) states that there is at least one prime number in range [n^2, (n + 1)^2] for every positive integer n.

Implement the function legendre that takes in an input parameter n and tests Legendre's conjecture over a range of numbers from 1 up to the input number n.

This means if the input is 4, you should check that there is at least one prime between 1^2 and 2^2, and at least one prime between 2^2 and 3^2, and at least one prime between 3^2 and 4^2, and at least one prime between 4^2 and 5^2.

Comment: You should also check that the question is not one that makes us do all the work for you.

Comment: You should post the code you already tried and then ask a question about the specific part that isn't working the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

For smaller n, just [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to n^2 for primes and brute-force check. For larger n -- apply a good primality test such as [Rabin-Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to the numbers of the form 6a+1, 6a+5 (until you find a prime) in the ranges of the form [k^2,(k+1)^2] for k <= n.

Comment: I love these kinds of answers, where it's obvious that OP is getting exactly what they asked for. ;-D